# How do I keep images always on top without using Z-Index?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a fairly simple website attached below. When hovering over an underlined word, there is an image that appears right at the position of the word.

The images are supposed to be always on top, no matter what.
But the underlined words keep appearing on top of the images. (See code snippet). I know there must be something conflicting in the order of my elements! Please help, I am a bloody beginner.

I have tried to set a Z-Index, but that doesn't work at all.

I hope you understand my problem here!

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: black;
}

#wrapper {
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
}

p {
    color: white;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
}

.gallery-image {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    transform: translate(0,calc(1em - 50%));
  max-width: 50vw;
    max-height: 75vh;
    height: auto;
}

.gallery-link {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.gallery-link:hover > .gallery-image{
    display: flex;  
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    
<div class="section">
<p>Title<br>
Nor is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain
<span class="gallery-link"><img  class="gallery-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/590_Madison_Ave_IBM_08.jpg" >
vulnerability </span> of any.<br>
The once <span class="gallery-link">colorful rug<img class="gallery-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7c/Ornamentglas_B_-_Ansicht_1.jpg/1000px-Ornamentglas_B_-_Ansicht_1.jpg"></span> has been <span class="gallery-link">broken down<img class="gallery-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/CocooningⓒShin%2C_Kyungsub.jpg" ></span> but is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain.<br>
End Quote
</p>
</div>          
</div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: black;
}

#wrapper {
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
}

p {
    color: white;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
}

.gallery-image {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    transform: translate(0,calc(1em - 50%));
  max-width: 50vw;
    max-height: 75vh;
    height: auto;
z-index: 1000;
}

.gallery-link {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.gallery-link:hover > .gallery-image{
    display: flex; 
z-index: 1000; 
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    
<div class="section">
<p>Title<br>
Nor is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain
<span class="gallery-link"><img  class="gallery-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/590_Madison_Ave_IBM_08.jpg" >
vulnerability </span> of any.<br>
The once <span class="gallery-link">colorful rug<img class="gallery-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7c/Ornamentglas_B_-_Ansicht_1.jpg/1000px-Ornamentglas_B_-_Ansicht_1.jpg"></span> has been <span class="gallery-link">broken down<img class="gallery-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/CocooningⓒShin%2C_Kyungsub.jpg" ></span> but is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain.<br>
End Quote
</p>
</div>          
</div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.gallery-image {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    transform: translate(0,calc(1em - 50%));
  max-width: 50vw;
    max-height: 75vh;
    height: auto;
}

.gallery-link {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.gallery-link:hover > .gallery-image{
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).